# One out of Infinity: Interpolating polynomials

Tags: code-golf, polynomials

For this challenge, **when given a list of (x,y) points your submission needs to output a polynomial function that goes through all of them**.

For example, if your points were `[(0,0), (2,5)]`, you could return `y = 2.5*x` or `y = x + 1/4x^2`.

- All points passed in will consist only of integers
- Two points will never have the same `y` value
- Your function be of the form `y = a*x^n + ... b*x^m`.   Reducing of terms is allowed.
- Constants (the exponent and coefficient) can either be in decimal or fractional form.  Decimals should be accurate to at least 3 decimal places
- You should be able to handle an arbitrary number of points
- Output must be a string starting with "y=". Whitespace anywhere in the string is fine.

## Test cases

Note, the given output is not the only valid output, just one of the possibilities.

```
(1,4)                                                    -> y=x+3
(0,0), (1,8)                                             -> y=8x
(0,6), (-1,90)                                           -> y=-84x+6
(6,4), (70,4), (-1,-6)                                   -> y=−10/497x^2+760/497x−316/71
(4,5), (5,6), (6,7)                                      -> y=x+1
(20,1), (-20,1), (0,5), (10, 4), (11,12), (17,4), (2,4)  -> y=488137/10424165400x^6−643187/473825700x^5−87561839/10424165400x^4+550999039/1042416540x^3−21590713027/5212082700x^2+300110420/52120827x+5
```

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so make your answers as short as possible in your favorite language!

Comment: Your title says something about plotting but the challenge about outputting polynomials. Having the corresponding results for your test cases would probably help clear this up (and make the test cases a lot more useful).

Comment: Also how about built-ins? (Mathematica's is `InterpolatingPolynomial` so it's probably not at risk of winning.)

Comment: Builtins are fine.

Comment: The output needs to be a string. The input is flexible

Comment: Can coefficients in the output be (string representations of) floats instead of fractions? Say with 4 decimals?

Comment: Does the output need `y=`? Do exponents have to be explicitly listed?

Comment: @LuisMendo yes.

Comment: PS: I think you know about the existence of the sandbox by now :D

Comment: @flawr I know, I didn't expect so many problems when posting this challenge.

Comment: I don't think so. I'm organizing input as a list of x,y pairs

Comment: You are right. Sorry

Comment: Bah, it *is* a duplicate. I thought I did a pretty good search as well.

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 38 bytes

```
ynq3$ZQ'y=' '%+fx^%i'btn:qP&vYDh1J3-h)
```

Inputs are an array with the *x* values and an array with the *y* values.

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=eW5xMyRaUSd5PScgJyUrZnheJWknYnRuOnFQJnZZRGgxSjMtaCk&input=WzYgNzAgLTFdCls0IDQgLTZd)

```
y          % Inplicitly take the two inputs, and push another copy of the first
nq         % Get its length minus 1. This is the required polynomial degree.
3$ZQ       % Coefficients of polynomial fitted to those data (`polyfit`)
'y='       % Push this string
'%+fx^%i'  % Push format string for `sprintf`
b          % Bubble up the polynomial coefficients to the top of the stack
tn:qP      % Duplicate and produce [n n-1  ... 0] where n is the polynomial degree.
           % These are the exponents
&v         % Concatenate vertically. This gives a 2D array with the coefficients in
           % the first row and the exponents in the second
YD         % Apply `sprintf` to this array with previous format string. The array
           % is read in column-major order: down, then across
h          % Concatenate 'y=' and formatted string representing the polynomial
1J3-h)     % The string ends in '...x^0'. Remove last three chars to delete this.
           % Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python2 + sympy, <strike>61</strike> 58 bytes

```py
from sympy import*;print interpolate(input("y="),var("x"))
```

Comment: You can use `var` instead of `Symbol`. Also, not that it matters, but `input("y=")` gets rid of that unbalanced spacing around `=`.

Answer (score 1):

## Matlab (with Symbolic Toolbox), 52 bytes

Using builtins for calculating an interpolation polynomial, and then converting it to a symbolc expression for pretty printing and back to a string for the actual output. This function takes two lists of coordinates, e.g. `[6,70,-1]` and `[4,4,-6]` for the fourth test case.

```
 @(x,y)['y=',char(poly2sym(polyfit(x,y,numel(x)-1)))]
```

Comment: I think this should be titled "Matlab with Symbolic Toolbox". Good job!

Comment: Here it was kinda obvious, but many times I don't even know whether I'm using one of those toolboxes. =)